# Syncfusion ASP.NET Core : how to get value in cshtml after DataBinding?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, razor, syncfusion

I am using Syncfusion component in my ASP.NET Core 7.0 project. This is my `cshtml` markup:

```
<ejs-grid id="userstbl" allowSorting="true" allowPaging="true"
          toolbarClick="toolbarClick" toolbar="@(new List<string>() { "Add", "Edit", "Delete", "Cancel", "Update" })">
    <e-grid-pagesettings pageCount="6" pageSize="50"></e-grid-pagesettings>
    <e-grid-editSettings allowAdding="true" allowDeleting="true" allowEditing="true" mode="Normal"></e-grid-editSettings>
    <e-data-manager url="/Users/FetchData" adaptor="UrlAdaptor"></e-data-manager>
    <e-grid-columns>
        <e-grid-column headerText="First Name" field="FirstName"></e-grid-column>
        <e-grid-column headerText="Family" field="Family"></e-grid-column>
    </e-grid-columns>
</ejs-grid>
```

And this is my backend for binding the data :

```
public IActionResult FetchData([FromBody] DataManagerRequest dm)
{
    IEnumerable DataSource = _userRepository.GetUserList();
    DataOperations operation = new DataOperations();
        
    int count = DataSource.Cast<UserListViewModel>().Count();

    if (dm.Skip != 0)
    {
        DataSource = operation.PerformSkip(DataSource, dm.Skip); //Paging
    }

    if (dm.Take != 0)
    {
        DataSource = operation.PerformTake(DataSource, dm.Take);
    }

    return dm.RequiresCounts ? Json(new { result = DataSource, count = count }) : Json(DataSource);
}
```

As you can see, I have a parameter called `count`. But I don't know how to get its value on the client side...

Answer (score 0):

Based on your query, you want to get the returned count from the server in the client side. We are not able to get the datasource returned in the client side as this will be handled by source and set directly to the grid internally. However, you can get the total record count in the client side by using the property ‘**grid.pagerModule.pageSettings.totalRecordsCount**’.